# Pandas aggregate values by years but keep original TimeSeries index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series of monthly data. I'd like to sum aggregate the values by year but then keep the original TimeSeries index. This is probably best illustrated by example:

```python
# April 2012 to Nov 2053
dates = pd.date_range('2012-04-01',periods=500,freq='MS')

# Random time series over date range
a = pd.Series(np.arange(500), index=dates)

# Almost works but I'm missing the last 7 months:
# May 2053 to Nov 2053
b = a.resample('AS-APR', how='sum').resample('MS', fill_method='pad')
```

Any idea how I can get`b` to contain the full 500 time periods including the missing last 7 months? They need to be pad filled from the value in April 2053.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reindex instead:

```
b = a.resample('AS-APR', how='sum').reindex(a.index, method='pad')
```

This way you will get the same index as the original Series object, padded as you wanted.

The problem with `resample` is that when you first resampled `a`, the last entry become april 2053. So when you do your second resampling the end date will be 2053-04-01. So it did the correct resampling but the first one moved the end date from november to april.

If you would want to do a different frequency than the original array, you could do it again using this method:

```
b = a.resample('AS-APR', how='sum').reindex(a.resample('D').index, method='pad')
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why I couldn't find this in the documentation but I thought I might get a quicker answer here than continuing slogging through.