# pandas group by but keep original index and duplicate aggregate values

Tags: python, pandas

I have an integer indexed `pd.Series` with dtype `datetime64[ns]` called `timestamps`. (`timestamps` is sorted but this shouldn't matter)

I would like to calculate another series called `first_on_day` with the same index and the same dtype that represents the earliest time on the day.

The following code works:

```py
first_on_day = timestamps.groupby(timestamps.dt.date).apply(lambda series: pd.Series(series.min(), index=series.index))
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to doing this?

Related: [Pandas aggregate values by years but keep original TimeSeries index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485951/pandas-aggregate-values-by-years-but-keep-original-timeseries-index)

Comment: Can you add some dummy data?

Comment: Here you go: `pd.Series(pd.date_range('2001', '2002', freq='h'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want:

```
timestamps.groupby(timestamps.dt.date).transform("min")
```